# Is there a way to get element's offset in predicates passed to std algorithms?

Tags: c++, c++17, std

The predicates/operators used in the [Algorithms library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) accept elements by the respective iterators' value_type. I would like to write a predicate that uses the element's offset in the range.

For example, consider the following [code](https://godbolt.org/z/655vKv):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    auto offset_value_mismatch = [&v](int const & x){
        return (x != (&x-&v.front()));
    };

    return std::any_of(v.begin(), v.end(), offset_value_mismatch);
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a "nice" way (i.e. better than what I presented above) to find the element's offset in the range?
2. Is the technique above guaranteed to work for any data type (in place of `int`)? Because `const &` can bind to an r-value I'm worried I might get the address of some temporary copy.
3. Can something similar be implemented for associative (not continuous) data structures?
4. Do any of the answers change if I use the algorithm overloads accepting an std::ExecutionPolicy?

---

EDIT:

More information about my problem:
Consider a multi-dimensional data structure created on top of a `std::vector`. In this data structure the indices are "managed", so that I can perform some action on all data structures simultaneously. Moreover, the data-type can itself be indices.

When I modify the indices I therefore need to know if there's some relation between the "domain" indices and the "range" indices.

To this point, I used a loop. I'd like to see if I can improve performance by using the standard's parallel algorithms.

---

EDIT #2:

I ended up implementing a simple sequential loop-based algorithm for (rare) cases where a certain index type appears in both domain and range.
For other cases the exercise above is unnecessary and I get about 60% speed-up with `par_unseq` execution policy! (but not with `par`, for some reason).

Comment: "I would like to write a predicate that uses the element's offset in the range" And what problem, exactly, would you like to solve by doing so?

Comment: you could write a loop instead of using the algorithm

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm implementing a multi-dimensional data structure using a (1D) std-vector. The 1D-offset which I'm trying to get is used to calculate the various indices, which is important for various book-keeping purposes.

Comment: @idclev463035818 See question 4. I'm trying to improve my "loop" implementation.

Comment: I think the best solutions for you will depend on what algorithms you need to use. But I question why you're reinventing this wheel in the first place (see, for example, `boost::multi_array`).

Comment: I could imagine creating your own iterator class (templated on container or other iterator type) that wraps up an iterator along with an index. Then `operator++` would increment both the index and the underlying iterator, while `operator*` could return a pair containing the index and a reference to the element. But I don't know enough about writing iterators to fill in all the details (in particular, I think `operator*` is supposed to return a reference to the value type, not a pair *containing* a reference).

Comment: @ArthurTacca I thought about it. While this can indeed address all the issues I presented, it is arguably less elegant than the solution above...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the book-keeping I mentioned is too complicated to achieve with a boost::multi_array

Comment: `boost::multi_array` *already is* "a multi-dimensional data structure".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't see what you're getting at. I need to expand on the functionallity provided by `boost::multi_array` significantly. The purpose of this exercise is to enable such expension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is there a "nice" way (i.e. better than what I presented above) to find the element's offset in the range?

No, not in general.

> 2. Is the technique above guaranteed to work for any data type

Almost (except you obviously have to change the type of the argument to correspond to whatever data type is being iterated). You would have to use `std::addressof` in order for it to work with types that overload the addressof operator (but who does that?).

> 3. Can something similar be implemented for associative data structures?

Not quite like that. What you've shown works, but only for contiguous iterators i.e. iterators for arrays (in general sense, which includes vectors and strings).

Assuming that you are using an algorithm that iterates the elements in order (this is where execution policy is indeed important), then a general solution is to use an accumulator:

```
auto offset_value_mismatch = [](auto& x) {
    static int i;
    return i++ == x;
}
```

> 4. Do any of the answers change if I use the algorithm overloads accepting an std::ExecutionPolicy?

Both subtraction of address, and the accumulator only work with sequential algorithms and not the parallel ones. Technically the accumulator could be made to work with a parallel policy (but not unordered) using locks, but there is no advantage in doing that as far as I know.

Comment: I'm trying to improve on the technique you presented as an answer to #3. I'm sorry I didn't make it clear. Please see edit.

Comment: maybe `static int i{};` ?

Comment: @max66 you can use the initialiser if you prefer. But it is not necessary. Objects in static storage are zero initialised.

Comment: Could you please provide some more information regarding question #2? How can you know you're always dealing with a reference to the original datum, even given some parallel implementation of `any_of`?

Comment: @BennyK The datatype is irrelevant. Good point about parallel implementation. I fixed the answer to 4.

Comment: Can you provide an example where the subtraction technique fails (for parallel implementations)?

Comment: @BennyK The standard says `Unless otherwise stated, implementations may make arbitrary copies of elements`. The address of the copy cannot be used in the pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the technique above guaranteed to work for any data type (in place of int)? Because const & can bind to an r-value I'm worried I might get the address of some temporary copy.

No. This will only work for `std::vector` or `std::array` or raw pointers which guarantees that all elements are stored in continuous memory. For them it would work for any data type stored there though. But this technique would lead to UB even for random access iterator from `std::deque` for example.

> Can something similar be implemented for associative data structures?

I doubt so as this does not even work for random access iterator, situation with forward iterator for example would be even worse, looks like you have XY problem and need to specify what you want to achieve.